# Asana Api Rails Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, asana

I am attempting to add an attachment to an Asana task.

My JSON request body is as follows:

```
request_body = {
  "data" => {
    "file" => "@#{attachment.tempfile}"
  }
}
```

I receive this output on the POST:

```
error: file: File is not an object
```

The "attachment" variable is a regular rails form attachment.

Any ideas?

-----EDIT-----

For anyone looking in the future, I figured it out using the Faraday gem. Here is the code I used:

```
connection = Faraday.new(:url => @uri) do |conn|
  conn.response :logger                
  conn.request :multipart
  conn.request :url_encoded
  conn.basic_auth(@api_key, '')
  conn.adapter :net_http 
end

payload = { :file => Faraday::UploadIO.new(file, file_type) }
response = connection.post(@uri, payload)
return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, that's actually the one case you can't use JSON - you need to do a form-encoded upload, otherwise you're just trying to set the "file" parameter to the string "@tmpfile.txt" (or what have you).

I'm not familiar with rails specifically but the real question here is "how to post a file upload from Rails" - the Asana endpoint here works exactly like all other form uploads.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the direction. I figured it out.